# Custom white balance setting algorithm

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I want to set white balance in  my camera app in android java using camera 2 api.I am using

```
    public static RggbChannelVector colorTemperature(int whiteBalance) {
        float temperature = (float) whiteBalance / 100;
        float red;
        float green;
        float blue;

        //Calculate red
        if (temperature <= 66)
            red = 255;
        else {
            red = temperature - 60;
            red = (float) (329.698727446 * (Math.pow((double) red, -0.1332047592)));
            if (red < 0)
                red = 0;
            if (red > 255)
                red = 255;
        }

        //Calculate green
        if (temperature <= 66) {
            green = temperature;
            green = (float) (99.4708025861 * Math.log(green) - 161.1195681661);
            if (green < 0)
                green = 0;
            if (green > 255)
                green = 255;
        } else {
            green = temperature - 60;
            green = (float) (288.1221695283 * (Math.pow((double) green, -0.0755148492)));
            if (green < 0)
                green = 0;
            if (green > 255)
                green = 255;
        }

        //calculate blue
        if (temperature >= 66)
            blue = 255;
        else if (temperature <= 19)
            blue = 0;
        else {
            blue = temperature - 10;
            blue = (float) (138.5177312231 * Math.log(blue) - 305.0447927307);
            if (blue < 0)
                blue = 0;
            if (blue > 255)
                blue = 255;
        }
        return new RggbChannelVector((red / 255) * 2, (green / 255), (green / 255), (blue / 255) * 2);
    }
```

to set white balance but it is not that accurate if anyone know any algorithm please let me know.

in default camera app of my mobile result i am gatting at 5500 is vary different from above algorithm.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.